# Keras: InvalidArgumentError caused by placeholder when setting initial_states of LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to build a "recurrent" layer in Keras which contains multiple predefined layers (amongst others two lstm layers).

The general scheme is to use a keras model as layer which contains the simple layers I need, instantiate it and apply it multiple times to an input and its own outputs (thus creating multiple "nodes" of the model/layer with shared weights)

For the LSTMs to work properly I need to pass the cell and hidden state between the nodes.

This is a simplified version, which should emulate a normal LSTM:

```
def silly_lstm():  # the model-layer

  input_1 = Input(shape=(1,4), name='input_1')
  input_c = Input(shape=(2,), name='input_c')
  input_h = Input(shape=(2,), name='input_here_happens_the_error')

  out, cell, hidden = LSTM(2, return_state=True, name='lstm')
                              (input_1, initial_state=[input_c, input_h])

  return Model(inputs=[input_1, input_c, input_h],
                  outputs=[out, cell, hidden], name ='silly_lstm')

def silly_lstm_model():  # the actual model 

  i1 = Input(shape=(1,4), name='i1')  # the external input
  i2 = Input(shape=(2,), name='i2')   # initializer of the cell state
  i3 = Input(shape=(2,), name='i3')   # initializer of the hidden state

  lstm = silly_lstm()

  # the layer is "recurrently" applied multiple times
  o1, o2, o3 = lstm([i1, i2, i3])
  o1, o2, o3 = lstm([i1, o2, o3])

  model = Model(inputs=[i1, i2, i3], outputs=[o1, o2, o3])

  return model


model = silly_lstm_model()

i = [np.zeros((1,1,4)), np.zeros((1,2)), np.zeros((1,2))]
model.predict(i)
```

I get the following error (which goes away when I do not set the initial states in silly_lstm):

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_here_happens_an_error' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
```

The Traceback is this:

```
    Caused by op 'input_here_happens_an_error', defined at:
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 265, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 112, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1431, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 102, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-82-dd9a4619cb90>", line 1, in <module>
    model = silly_lstm_model_3()
  File "<ipython-input-81-b0023bfb8995>", line 89, in silly_lstm_model_3
    lstm = silly_lstm()
  File "<ipython-input-81-b0023bfb8995>", line 5, in silly_lstm
    input_h = Input(shape=(2,), dtype='float32', name='input_here_happens_an_error')
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 1455, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 1364, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 504, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1746, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 4026, in _placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Try upgrading Keras and Tensorflow and see the issue would resolve.

Comment: I am restricted to an older tensorflow version (1.8).

Comment: Can't you upgrade Keras either?

Comment: Updating Keras to 2.2.4 actually solved it. Thank you very much for insisting!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, upgrading Keras to the latest version (2.2.4) resolved the issue.